# Sphinx indexer doesn't take into account mem_limit in config

Tags: sphinx

I'm trying to use `sphinx 3.1.1` with plain index for autocomplete function. The problem is that I get `out of memory` error each time I run indexer despite there is mem_limit option in my config:

```
indexer 
{
  mem_limit = 2048M
}
```

If it makes sense I'm using tsvpipe as data source:

```
source autocomplete
{
  type = tsvpipe
  tsvpipe_command = cat /var/lib/sphinx/tmp/*.tsv
  tsvpipe_field = value
}
```

The error message:

```
FATAL: out of memory (unable to allocate 10737418248 bytes)
```

Comment: How big are your CSV files? Does it work if try importing less files (or smaller files)

Comment: There are above 2000 files from few KB to few MB, all together 1.3 Gb. I've tried to merge all of them to one file, but the problem is still takes place.

Comment: Replacing min_inflix_len to min_prefix_len in my index config resolved problem.

Comment: Ah yes, infix indexing can significantly increase memory size (non-linearly). I suspect `mem_limit`config only applies to one specific part of indexing (for example storing the doclist), but has sphinx has grown and added more features, other functions end up using memory too, that don't (overall) honour mem_limit